# Firefox and Chrome redirecting IPv6 to Google search

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, ipv6

There are already answers how to teach those browsers to resolve the targets (enable ipv6 dns),
but my problem is, when I enter an address (including http):

```
http://2001:db8:0:1::10:1ff
http://2001:0DB8:0000:0001:0000:0000:0010:01FF
```

The browser (most recent Chrome & Firefox) redirects me to the Google Search.

How do I get the browsers to actually connect to the addresses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IPv6 address in URLs must be surrounded by brackets.

Try :

```
http://[2001:db8:0:1::10:1ff]
http://[2001:0DB8:0000:0001:0000:0000:0010:01FF]
```

Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax :
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: Still not working here... it says that network is unreachable, although the corresponding ipv4 address for the same host is reachable...